# Activity has Leaked window Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-activity

Faço uma conexão com MySQL e ele me retorna um JSON que eu jogo numa lista de produtos. Quando clico em algum desses itens ele pega o ID (chamo de PID no código) do produto e manda pra outra Acitivity. Nesta outra Activity o ID é recuperado, e feito uma nova conexão com o MySQL pra me retornar os dados daquele produto.
O problema é que quando clica em um desses produtos, na hora de ir pra outra activity, o aplicativo simplesmente apresenta o erro "Unfortunately, (nome do app) has been stopped."
O estranho é que isso acontece às vezes só. Às vezes abre normalmente a segunda Acitivity, às vezes dá esse erro aí.

(ps.: usei este artigo como base: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

**Logcat:**

```
        14166-14166/com.example.victorcatao.booktrade E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.victorcatao.booktrade.DetalhesLivros has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1994769 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
        at com.example.victorcatao.booktrade.DetalhesLivros$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(DetalhesLivros.java:97)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
        at com.example.victorcatao.booktrade.DetalhesLivros.onCreate(DetalhesLivros.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**AllProductsActivity.java** (primeira Activity):

```
 public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_AUTOR = "autor";
private static final String TAG_PRECO = "preco";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DetalhesLivros.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

}


/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregando livros. Aguarde...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL - pega a resposta JSON do php
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String autor = c.getString(TAG_AUTOR);
                    String preco = c.getString(TAG_PRECO);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    //jogando os dados no textview
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_AUTOR, autor);
                    map.put(TAG_PRECO, "R$ "+preco);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 *
                 * JOGANDO OS VALORES DENTRO DO LISTVIEW*/
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_AUTOR, TAG_PRECO},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.autor, R.id.preco });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

**DetalhesLivros.java** (Segunda Activity):

```
public class DetalhesLivros extends ListActivity {

String pid;
TextView txtNome, txtNome2, txtAutor, txtPreco, txtDescricao, txtDDD, txtTelefone, txtEmailContato;
Button btnEnviarEmail;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://localhost/android_connect/get_some_products.php?pid="; //variável pid entra aqui

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_AUTOR = "autor";
private static final String TAG_PRECO= "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRICAO = "descricao";
private static final String TAG_DDD = "ddd";
private static final String TAG_TELEFONE = "telefone";
private static final String TAG_TIPO = "tipo";
private static final String TAG_EMAILCONTATO = "emailcontato";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhes_livros);

    //RECUPERANDO O ID DO PRODUTO (PID)
    Intent i = getIntent();
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

}


/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetalhesLivros.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL - pega a resposta JSON do php
        //Relacionando a url+numero do id, que será pego pelo PHP e blablabla
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products + pid, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products

                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String autor = c.getString(TAG_AUTOR);
                String preco = c.getString(TAG_PRECO);
                String descricao = c.getString(TAG_DESCRICAO);
                String ddd = c.getString(TAG_DDD);
                String telefone = c.getString(TAG_TELEFONE);
                String emailcontato = c.getString(TAG_EMAILCONTATO);


                //inserindo os textos nos campos
                txtNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
                txtNome2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNome2);
                txtAutor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAutor);
                txtPreco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPreco);
                txtDescricao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
                txtDDD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDDD);
                txtTelefone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTelefone);
                txtEmailContato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmailContato);

                txtNome.setText(name);
                txtNome2.setText(name);
                txtAutor.setText("("+autor+")");
                txtPreco.setText("R$"+preco);
                txtDescricao.setText(descricao);
                txtDDD.setText(ddd);
                txtTelefone.setText(telefone);
                txtEmailContato.setText(emailcontato);


            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * *
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema. O fato é que não pode acessar uma view e fazer um .setText pelo doInBackground. Eu joguei os resultados no onPostExecute() e dei .setText de lá.

Se alguém tiver o mesmo problema algum dia.....